# How do you set one parameter in a two Dimensional array to a single array?

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to know how to set the row of a 2D array to the first element in a single array and the columns to the second element

```
/**
 * findHighestLocation finds the row and column indexes of the
 * highest value in the given two dimensional array.
 * @param table The two dimensional array for which to find 
 *              the highest value
 * @return a newly created one dimensional array of size 2. The
 *         first element contains the row index of the highest value 
 *         in table. The second element contains the column index
 *         of the highest value in table. */
public static int[] findHighestLocation(int[][] table) {
    int [] highestLocation = new int [2];
    int largest = table[0][0];

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
    {
        if (table[i][i] > largest)
        {
            largest = table[i][i];
            highestLocation [0] = table[i][];
            highestLocation [1] = table[i][];
        }
    }
    return highestLocation;
}
```

Comment: This isn’t related to JavaScript at all.

Comment: My bad thought i didn't think I put that their. Can you help with the code

Comment: The title and the code comments don't seem to match up.  Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  Provide example input and expected output.